# Unset array if sub array key value found in another array

Tags: php, arrays

```
            $myarray = Array
            (
                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 84
                        [Name] => Confirm Mailing of SSDI App
                        [CaseId] => 0
                    )

                [10] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 17
                        [Name] => Upload Fee Agreement (signed)
                        [CaseId] => 0
                    )

                [11] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 41
                        [Name] => Upload 827 (1st) (signed)
                        [CaseId] => 0
                    )

                [12] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 39
                        [Name] => Upload 3288 (signed)
                        [CaseId] => 0
                    )

                [13] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 37
                        [Name] => Upload 16-F6 sig page (signed)
                        [CaseId] => 0
                    )

                [14] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 38
                        [Name] => Upload 8001-BK sig page (signed)
                        [CaseId] => 0
                    )

            )
```

I have a master array as above and  another one array as below

```
            $anotherarray = Array
            (
                [1] => 41
                [2] => 39
                [3] => 37
            )
```

I have to unset from master array which Id match with `$another` array, without for loop, please help me best solution.

for example `$anotherarray` array has a three id 41,39,37 so I have to unset array from master array like 11,12,13.

Comment: `for example $anotherarray array has a three id 41,39,37 so i have to unset array from master array like 11,12,13.` ? controversial. why 11,12,13?

Comment: Why without for loop?

Comment: Because if it can be done without loop then it better for performance because my script has more then 10k line so take care to avoid unnecessary looping

Answer (score 0):

use a new array to store the id and the index, so that you not have to traverse the array every time.

```
$keys_map = array_flip(array_map(function($v){return $v['id'];}, $array));
foreach($anotherarray as $v)
{
    unset($array[$keys_map[$v]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$myarray = array_filter($myarray, function($value) use ($anotherarray) {
    return !in_array($value['id'], $anotherarray);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$arrFinal = array();
array_walk($myarray, function(&$value, $key)  use (&$anotherarray, &$arrFinal) {
    if(!in_array($value['id'],$anotherarray)){
        return $arrFinal[$key] = $value;
    }
});


print_r($arrFinal);
```